Seting up FreeRadius with 2FA to authenticate Local Users RDP logins
I'm tasked with setting up authentication of local users to rdp using FreeRadius and google authenticator. However I am very new to this. So my questions are

Is the above setup possible?

if yes, how can this be done?



Is the above setup possible? No.

This probably isn't a good forum to "travel the country looking for a ring". A better approach would be to evaluate the vendors with multifactor solutions for Windows. Windows has supported traditional smart cards for 20 years, and there are several vendors with multifactor solutions that use an authenticator application.


No, that is not possible with Windows.
see above

Consider Active Directory.

How would you advise this to be achieved without using the likes of duo, rublon etc.

How is that is not possible with Windows ambiguous?
